# pygooglechart define data encoding

Tags: python, google-visualization, pygooglechart

when using `chart.add_date([1,2,3,4,5])` it creates the URL with "`chd=e:LNYAczgATN5m`", it is encoded the data but i want to be of type text as "`chd=t:1,2,3,4,5`"

What is the function that can do this ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

pygooglechart attempts to detect the source data range, and automatically decide what data encoding type to use. See the `def data_class_detection()` method in the source:

https://github.com/gak/pygooglechart/blob/master/pygooglechart.py#L518

To force a certain type of encoding, you can call `get_url(self, data_class=None)` and specify the `data_class` as `TextData`, e.g.:

```
import pygooglechart as pygc
chart = pygc.SimpleLineChart(250, 100)
chart.add_data([1, 3, 2, 4, 5])

>>> chart.get_url(data_class=pygc.TextData)
'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=250x100&chd=t:0.0,40.0,20.0,60.0,80.0'

>>> chart.get_url()
'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=250x100&chd=e:AAMzZmmZzM'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use chart.download() then the data_class option of get_url is not available.

You can use a subclass to work around this problem:

```
# force the TextData type for any data (real number instead of aabaa)
class LineChart(SimpleLineChart):
   def data_class_detection(self, data):
       return TextData
```

and then use this class instead of SimpleLineChart